# JQuery/JS Input Iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am getting incorrect results from my logic and I'm not sure why. Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.
I have dynamically created cards with 1-3 inputs per card. I am trying to iterate through the cards and collect the input values for each individual card but instead I keep getting the input values for all the cards for each iteration

html

```
<div class="card">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="B">
</div>
<div class="card">
    <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
</div>
```

js

```
arr = []
$('.card').each(function (i, obj) {
    $('.sample').each (function (i, obj) {
        val = $(this).val()
        arr.push(val)
    })
})
```

I was expecting arr[A, B] and arr[A]
but i get arr[A, B, A] and arr[A, B, A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this result due to inner loop is executing for all samples div present into HTML.

Use `$(obj).find('.sample')` instead of `$('.sample')`. It will execute for sample div within card div.

```js
var arr = []

$('.card').each(function (i, obj) {
        var ele = [];
    $(obj).find('.sample').each (function (i, obj) {
        val = $(this).val()
        ele.push(val)
    })
        arr.push(ele)
})

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="B">
</div>
<div class="card">
    <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is expected.

There are many ways to achieve what you want: *"I was expecting arr[A, B] and arr[A]"*

But for me, I would go for adding more distinctions in your classes:

> card-0, card-1, and so on should be coded by you

html

```
<div class="card-0 cards">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
     <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="B">
</div>
<div class="card-1 cards">
    <input type="hidden" class="sample" value="A">
</div>
```

js

```
var mainArray = [];
var cardsCount = $('.cards').length;
for (var i1 = 0; i1 < cardsCount; i1++) {
     var arr = [];
   $(".card-" + i1 + " :input").each(
      function() {
            arr.push($(this).val());
      }
   );
   mainArray.push(arr);

}
alert(mainArray[0]);
alert(mainArray[1]);
```